# CASE to sum column based on boolean

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I have:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(X) AS columnA,

CASE WHEN Y = TRUE THEN 'VAR' ELSE 'VAR2' END
```

Then I group by to get the counts but how do I sum X when Y is TRUE only? Or get the % of A in relation to true/untrue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I sum X when Y is TRUE only?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Y = TRUE THEN X ELSE 0 END)
```